# Access method and use it in another class

Tags: c#, .net

I have made method `UpdateLogList()` to update listView in my code and it worked. Now is created this class that i need and when i try to use `UpdateLogList()` i have error

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.UpdateLogList(string)'

And can't use it inside other class.

I found many questions similar to this one but not a single solution works for me.

How i can make this to work

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private class MyInit : AnotherClass
    {
        public override void Init()
        {
            base.Init();

            // some action occur i need to update here
            Form1.UpdateLogList("Text i wan't to set")
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void UpdateLogList(string data)
    {
        logList.Items.Add(dateNow + " - " + data);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you can have multiple *instances* of `Form1` and each of those instances will have it's *own* `logList` (presumably). You cannot call `Form1.UpdateLogList` because it doesn't know *which instance you're talking about*.

Comment: Form1 is class name. this.UpdateLogList(...) or UpdateLogList(...) for short.

Comment: Can you guys give me some link or example how to solve things like this or help with something instead of giving my answer negative points ?

Answer (score 0):

try to make it static.

```
public static void UpdateLogList(string data){//your code here}
```

Comment: If i make it static then i can use it only outside or my Form1.

Answer (score 0):

You're (presumably) using a member, `logList`, in `UpdateLogList`, so you can't make it static. Because it isn't static, you can't call it without a target like you're doing here:

```
Form1.UpdateLogList("Text i wan't to set");
```

Change it to call the method as an instance method:

```
this.UpdateLogList("Text i wan't to set"); // `this.` is optional
```

Now, when you want to call this method from another class, make sure you have a reference to your form. You'll be able to call it:

```
myFormInstance.UpdateLogList("Text i wan't to set");
```

Comment: This is not working either, my instance is Form1 and i have only 1 form.